# Sample invocations structured incorrectly

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-developers-console

I've matched the display name of my Assistant app and the sample invocations but after saving the invocations then reloading the page, I get the error message that reads **_
For en: Your sample invocations are structured incorrectly. Make sure they all start with a trigger phrase, include either your Action name or pronunciation, and successfully invoke your Action. Learn more about the phrases that will invoke your Action._** so I can't publish my app.
[Image showing the error message in red.. with the sample invocations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPU27.png)

Answer (score 4):

Some of the invocation phrases you have are not valid invocation phrases that can get to your Action. If you only have a single intent to start your Action, you can just have a single example: **talk to animal reproductive life**.

As these are sample invocations, they only appear in your directory page.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the other invocations just remaining with one and now it's clean and good.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the trigger phrases/ invocations [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/languages-locales).. As you can see there are three types: speak to, talk to, and ask.

Just follow those examples and make sure your invocation "name" is identical to the name given under the Invocation section of the AoG Project.